# "An operations error occurred" from DirectoryServices

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I'm trying to use System.DirectoryServices to query an Active Directory server, using LDAP.  My code can (apparently) connect and authenticate, but when my first DirectorySearcher FindAll() method is called, I only get:

```
[DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.]
```

Picking apart the exception in the debugger has been remarkably unproductive.  It seems to have pretty much no other information associated with it.  The online docs aren't helping me, either.

I'm sure it's probably something I'm doing wrong, but what?  Is there any way to tell what kind of problem this is?

Comment: Can you post the code which does the search?

Comment: Shoban: How much context do you want?  What exactly are you looking for?  The line that throws is literally `var results = ds.FindAll();` (ds a `DirectorySearcher`).  There's really no setup besides creating this object.

Comment: it can be due to a lot of different reasons.  Usually, it's because of your wrong environment setup.  Did you successfully get bind to a DirectoryEntry object and show the properties inside that object?  Did you try using ADSI Edit connecting to the target domain first?

Comment: Can you show us the **whole** section of code - how do you set up your search? What LDAP path do you use? What options do you set on your directory searcher.... and please: **update** your original question by **editing** it - don't post code samples into comments, they're excruciatingly hard to decipher here......